# multiple bars and dual monitor not working after driver installation

Tags: radeon

Installed the drivers acording to the manual setup in [the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI), ran amdcccle and setup the dual display, enabled Xinerama so I can move stuff between monitors and now my desktop looks like

[image: this]

and the second monitor is white. I can move the mouse to it, but not the windows.

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Just noticed that everytime i apply something in amdcccle and reboot i get another bar, now i have 6 :D

Comment: So Alt clicked to remove the extra crap, but still no real dual monitor (drag windows between them)

Comment: getting one after every reboot, not related to applying changes to amdcccle =/

Comment: This unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.